# How can I include a core.js polyfill in ember?

Tags: ember-cli

I was under the impression that I could do:

```
app.import('bower_components/core.js/library/fn/object/entries.js');
```

But it's not resolving the imported portions of it. If I start linking it up myself I end up with:

```
app.import('bower_components/core.js/modules/_global.js');
app.import('bower_components/core.js/modules/_export.js');
app.import('bower_components/core.js/library/fn/object/entries.js');
```

And

> Module is not defined.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right okay it seems like I need to install `core.js` then build it:

```
npm run grunt build:es7.object.entries
```

Then include the product of that.